# How to fill the div elements with javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I have this code for showing data from MYSQL. I can fill the divs with innerHTML, but when I use += then it concates all the values in the array. But i need to create new elements in div. How should i implement it?

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
$(".dropdown-item").click( function() {
    var data = { action: 'get_data',
      id: $(this).attr('id')
      };
      var parent= document.getElementById('info-block bg-grey m-b-2 p-a');
      var name = document.getElementsByClassName('h4 underline-sm')[0];
      var job = document.getElementsByClassName('m-b-1')[3];
      var phone=document.getElementsByClassName('m-b-0')[6];
      var image= document.getElementsByClassName('col-sm-4 text-xs-right m-b-1')[0];
   jQuery.ajax({
        cache: false,
        url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
        data: data,
        dataType:'JSON',
        method: 'POST',
           success: function(response) {
            $.each(response, function(key, value){

            //

            name.innerHTML=response[key].firstname + ' ' + response[key].lastname;
            job.innerHTML ='<b>' + $.trim(response[key].job_title)  + ' <br>Tööruum: ' + $.trim(response[key].room) + '<br/><a href="mailto:' +  $.trim(response[key].email) + '>"' + $.trim(response[key].email)+ '</a></b>' ;
            phone.innerHTML=$.trim(response[key].phone) + ' ' + $.trim(response[key].cell_phone);
            image.innerHTML='<img src="'+ $.trim(response[key].image) +'" class="rounded-circle lg" alt="">';

                           });

        }  
   });
});
});
```

I'm adding a div from HTML also to show what div i need to fill and create with loop.

```
<div class="info-block bg-grey m-b-2 p-a-2">  <!--parent div-->
                    <h4 class="h4 underline-sm">  </h4>   <!--response[key].firstname+ ' ' response[key].lastname-->
                    <div class="col-sm-8 text-xs-left">
                        <p class="m-b-1"></p> <!--'<b>' + $.trim(response[key].job_title)  + ' <br>Tööruum: ' + $.trim(response[key].room) + '<br/><a href="mailto:' +  $.trim(response[key].email) + '>"' + $.trim(response[key].email)+ '</a></b>' -->
                        <p class="m-b-0"></p> <!--response[key].phone + ' ' + response[key].cell_phone-->
                    </div>
                    <div class=" col-sm-4 text-xs-right m-b-1">
                        <img src="" class="rounded-circle lg" alt="">  <!--to src response[key].image-->
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I don't need someone to do the work, but someone maby could explain how to use createelement, and how to create child-divs to parent div with DOM elements.

Thank you all for your time you spend to think on my problem.

Answer (score 2):

You could use jQuery append function to do that, here is a quick example:

```
$('.h4').append(response[key].firstname + ' ' + response[key].lastname);
```

OR

```
$('.underline-sm').append(response[key].firstname + ' ' + response[key].lastname);
```

Comment: its not working, it does nothing, if i do `var name=$( document.getElementsByClassName('h4 underline-sm')[0]));` and `name.append(response[key].firstname + ' ' + response[key].lastname);` It still concates the data from the array.

Answer (score 1):

Just a sample first create a wrapper div with id wrapper and create your required html in variable and append in the wrapper. for example

```
<div id="wrapper"></div> //this is your wrapper which holds all the html you want to insert
```

then in js

```
var html =  `<div>
              <h2>`
               + $.trim(response[key].job_title) +
             `</h2>`
             `<p class="`+response[key].firstname+ `">`
               + $.trim(response[key].phone) +
             `<p>
            </div>`

$("#wrapper").append(html);
```

it will append the required html inside wrapper. every new html will be appended inside wrapper but below the previous html. hope this gives you some idea

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/)  your div each time you need to create a new one with specific values:

```
$.each(response, function(key, value){
   var clonedEle = $('.info-block.bg-grey.m-b-2.p-a-2').clone();
   clonedEle.find('.h4.underline-sm').text(value.firstname+ ' ' + value.lastname);
   ...........
```

Your final code will be:

```js
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    $(".dropdown-item").click(function() {
        var data = { action: 'get_data',
            id: $(this).attr('id')
        };
        jQuery.ajax({
            cache: false,
            url: '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
            data: data,
            dataType:'JSON',
            method: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                $.each(response, function(key, value){
                    var clonedEle = $('.info-block.bg-grey.m-b-2.p-a-2').clone();
                    clonedEle.find('.h4.underline-sm').text(value.firstname+ ' ' + value.lastname);
                    clonedEle.find('.m-b-1').append('<b>' + $.trim(value.job_title)  + ' <br>Tööruum: ' +
                            $.trim(value.room) + '<br/><a href="mailto:' +  $.trim(value.email) + '>"' + $.trim(value.email)+ '</a></b>');
                    clonedEle.find('.m-b-0').text(value.phone + ' ' + value.cell_phone);
                    clonedEle.find('img.rounded-circle.lg').attr('src', value.image);
                    clonedEle.insertAfter('.info-block.bg-grey.m-b-2.p-a-2:first');
                });
            }
        })
    })
});
```

```js
var response = [{firstname: 'firstname1', job_title: 'job_title', room: 'room', email: 'email', phone: 'phone', cell_phone: 'cell_phone', image: 'image'},
    {firstname: 'firstname2', job_title: 'job_title', room: 'room', email: 'email', phone: 'phone', cell_phone: 'cell_phone', image: 'image'}]

$.each(response, function(key, value){
   var clonedEle = $('.info-block.bg-grey.m-b-2.p-a-2').clone();
    clonedEle.find('.h4.underline-sm').text(value.firstname+ ' ' + value.lastname);
    clonedEle.find('.m-b-1').append('<b>' + $.trim(value.job_title)  + ' <br>Tööruum: ' +
            $.trim(value.room) + '<br/><a href="mailto:' +  $.trim(value.email) + '>"' + $.trim(value.email)+ '</a></b>');
    clonedEle.find('.m-b-0').text(value.phone + ' ' + value.cell_phone);
    clonedEle.find('img.rounded-circle.lg').attr('src', value.image);
    clonedEle.insertAfter('.info-block.bg-grey.m-b-2.p-a-2:first');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="info-block bg-grey m-b-2 p-a-2">  <!--parent div-->
    <h4 class="h4 underline-sm">  </h4>   <!--response[key].firstname+ ' ' response[key].lastname-->
    <div class="col-sm-8 text-xs-left">
        <p class="m-b-1"></p> <!--'<b>' + $.trim(response[key].job_title)  + ' <br>Tööruum: ' + $.trim(response[key].room) + '<br/><a href="mailto:' +  $.trim(response[key].email) + '>"' + $.trim(response[key].email)+ '</a></b>' -->
        <p class="m-b-0"></p> <!--response[key].phone + ' ' + response[key].cell_phone-->
    </div>
    <div class=" col-sm-4 text-xs-right m-b-1">
        <img src="" class="rounded-circle lg" alt="">  <!--to src response[key].image-->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Its working, but i made a small mistake by question - the  `info-block.bg-grey.m-b-2.p-a-2` is wrapped another div wich creates a grid layout i think?
But when i change the `var clonedEle = ('.col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4');` and `clonedEle.insertAfter('.col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4');`` then the page shows empty?